# Cannot pass data in destroy signal of gtk2

Tags: c, linux, gtk, gtk2

Here is the code, I want to pass `my_pointer` to the `destroy` signal of a gtk window `GtkWidget *window`:

```
static gboolean destroy(GtkWidget *widget, GdkEvent *event, gpointer data) {
  printf("gpointer: %ld\n", data);
}

g_signal_connect (window, "destroy", G_CALLBACK(destroy), my_pointer);
```

But what I got is `1`, always `1`!

Any other signal works fine when I pass `my_pointer` to it, such as `focus-in-event`, `key-press-event` etc, but what's wrong with `destroy` signal? And `1` is not a pointer at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`destroy` signal](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWidget.html#GtkWidget-destroy) is different than the `destroy-event` signal.

The expected function prototype of the `destroy` signal's callback is the following:

```
void
user_function (GtkWidget *object,
               gpointer   user_data)
```

Whereas your function currently matches the `destroy-event` signal's callback:

```
gboolean
user_function (GtkWidget *widget,
               GdkEvent  *event,
               gpointer   user_data)
```

Change the return type and remove the second parameter of your function.

```
static void destroy(GtkWidget *widget, gpointer data) {
    printf("gpointer: %ld\n", data);
}
```

Comment: I found that myself after some debugging, there is only 2 arguments in the callback of `destroy` signal, without `GdkEvent`, thanks for you help!